# How to find if two or more texts are correlated

Tags: algorithm, nlp

Say we have two english texts T1 and T2 (disjoint no overlap ) cut out from a larger text T. Is there a way to figure out that T1 and T2 came from a single larger text?

For example , newspaper layout is in multi column text. Given two column of text from any where in newspaper , I want to find out whether these two column of text came from the same story.

Comment: can u give other example ?

Comment: If both texts "snippets" are part of a larger article written by a single author, then their are statistical NLP approaches that are good predictors of this.

Answer (score -2):

You didn't say which language/environment to use, but you can do this many different ways.  For example, in C you can use [strstr()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/?kw=strstr):

```
char *newspaper_text = "At 4:00 AM a terrible tragedy struck Rand's Pandy Panda Farm....";

char *potentional_excerpt = "Mr. Jibber's panda has been airborne ever since."

char *location_of_excerpt_in_text = strstr(newspaper_text, potentional_excerpt);

if(location_of_excerpt_in_text)
    printf("Excerpt found!\n");
```